# Capybara-Webkit: page.should have_content() not implemented?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have recently attempted to use:

```
Then(/^I should see "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  page.should have_content(arg1)
end
```

To query the page and see if a text exists on the page.

This worked fine with the default Capybara driver, but after setting the javascript driver to [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) and running the tests again I get:

```
  undefined method `find_xpath' for #<Capybara::Webkit::Driver:0x007fa3f00152e8> (NoMethodError)
  ./features/step_definitions/customer_steps.rb:12:in `/^I should see "(.*?)"$/'
  features/manage_customers.feature:10:in `Then I should see "ABC XYZ"'
```

I am using the javascript driver since I am also using AngularJS to populate my data.

**My questions:**

1. Are have_content() and page.has_content?() not implemented in [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit)?
2. What could be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there may be an issue with `capybara-webkit`: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/499

I added `gem 'capybara', '2.0.3'` to my gemfile for now and that seems to fix the issue.

Comment: I solved it by changing my gemfile to
gem 'capybara-webkit', git: 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit.git'

Just adding the git source worked cause it probably pulled a fixed dev version.